# Both code are perfectly valid , but which is semantically correct?

Tags: xhtml, accessibility, semantics, w3c-validation

Both code are perfectly valid , but which is semantically correct?

It has `<p>`

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>heading level 2</h2>
          <p>
             some long text here some long text here some long text 
             here some long text here some long text here some long 
             text here some long text here some long text here
         </p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

This is without `<p>`

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>heading level 2</h2>

           some long text here some long text here some long 
           text here some long text here some long text here 
           some long text here some long text here some long text here
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on if the text is a paragraph or not. It probably is, but it is hard to tell from the placeholder content.

(This assumes that having the content as an ordered list item is semantically correct in the first place.)

Comment: Dorward - Yes having `OL` is correct I think because here the heading of page is "Top 10 List" so I'm using. My question is I'm having a heading and some text inside `<li>`. for heading I think `<h2>` is ok but how semantic is the text which comes after the heading. And in my case there will always 1 heading and 1 paragraph inside `<li>`. Should i add `<p>` to content? will it make the content more accessible and screen reader compatible?

Comment: If you have a paragraph then it should be marked up as a `<p>`. If you have some text that is not a paragraph then it shouldn't.

Comment: Dorward - But text is long. It has 3-4 sentences. Should i consider this as a text or paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to keep the markup easily associable with the website. Therefore, I'd choose the `<p>` version so readers of my code could more easily follow the website's structure.

Comment: Structure just needs *an* element, a div would do as well as a paragraph for *structure*.

Comment: If the text is a paragraph, it's best to use a paragraph tag. Personally, I think that it's easier to associate a paragraph tag to a paragraph than a div to a paragraph.

Comment: It is no easier (OK, 4 characters easier). The semantics are better, but only **if** it is a paragraph.

Comment: Easier to -associate- not to write.